# Issues using the latest Psych with Rails 3.2.8 & ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I recently hit some JSON parse issues and discovered we are using a pretty old version of Psych and libyaml: Psych version: 1.2.2; Psych libyaml version: 0.1.4

The latest Psych has much better JSON parsing support (subset of YAML) and I verified this fixes my issues, however I'm having issues configuring our Rails app to use the latest Psych gem versus the Psych version bundled with ruby.
I simply add gem 'psych' in the gemfile and run bundle install according to the online docs.
Now when I try to run anything I hit errors:
uninitialized constant Psych::Streaming::ClassMethods (NameError)

While it makes no sense, I know whats going on here, internally Rails is using the OLD version of Psych::Streaming which doesn't have these new methods. When I debug I see it using the old dir (e.g. ~Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\1.9.1\psych\streaming.rb) versus the NEW lib it should be using (e.g. ~Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\psych-2.0.8\lib\psych\streaming.rb)

So this seems like general confusion where code in the new Psych gem is calling code from the old bundled Psych version. How do I get Rails to not use the old bundled version and use the latest Psych??

We're using an older version of Rails (3.2.8) and ruby (1.9.3-p125) and unfortunately upgrading is not an option for the project right now...

** UPDATE **

It seems like root causing this problem will be a nightmare so maybe I need a new approach. Is there a way to ONLY use the latest Psych gem in my new code, but let everything else (like the external ruby libs) continue using the old bundled version? We had no issues with the old Psych version until I started passing around & parsing more complex JSON in my new code...

Comment: How about renaming or deleting the old psych folder to make sure that one isn't loaded before the Gem version?

Comment: On those same lines, could you forcibly `require 'psych'` before Rails gets involved to make sure you get Gemfile version?  Are you using `rbenv` or `rvm`?  I wonder if those might help?  You might also try uninstalling all versions of `psych` and then re-bundle so you only have the one you want available to bundler and Rails (effectively what @Casper is recommending).

Comment: I'm sorry if it's not much of an answer, but failing to upgrade rails to at least the latest version of 3.2 is dangerous.   There are known security vulnerabilities in the rails stack that need to be addressed, and the minor version points should not be that big of a problem.

Comment: Thanks. I could not uninstall it but I did try removing the old Psych folder and remnants manually. However this caused a bunch of new errors where other ruby libs were referring to the old Psych code so method params were not matching and other messiness. I might be able to hack my way through this but I feel modifying ext. libs like this could lead to bad things and probably not a good direction to go in for our app that now has real customers...

Comment: What version of bundler are you using? I remember something from a while back where you couldn't specify psych in your Gemfile because Bundler had already loaded psych (to read the gemspecs)

Comment: Yes, I was also curious about Bundler, we are using 1.2.1.